# How to initialize database with Entity Framework and Membership tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have a MVC4 web application that use Entity Framework 5.0 Code First.

In Global.asax.cs I have a bootstrapper that initialize the Entity.Database, force the database to be initialized and initialize the database for the Membership. The code is this one:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseContextInitializer());
Database.Initialize(true);
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(DEFAULTCONNECTION, "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

The DatabaseContextInitializer is very simple for the moment:

```
public class DatabaseContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DatabaseContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext dbContext)
    {
        base.Seed(dbContext);
        db.Set<Workout>().Add(new Workout {Id = 1, Name = "My First workout user1"})

    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot create User to the membership with:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(DEFAULTCONNECTION, "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Because I have a problem with that the database is not created. How do you initialize some default user for your database with Entity Framework 5.0 and Asp.Net MVC 4?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Take a look at the [following article](http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/) for the recommended approach for seeding your database using migrations.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 application using the Internet Template
2. In your package manager console type the following command:

   ```
   enable-migrations
   ```
3. This will create a `~/Migrations/Configuration.cs` file in which you could seed your database:

   ```
   using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web.Security;
   using WebMatrix.WebData;

   internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MvcApplication1.Models.UsersContext>
   {
       public Configuration()
       {
           AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
       }

       protected override void Seed(MvcApplication1.Models.UsersContext context)
       {
           WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

           if (!Roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
           {
               Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");
           }

           if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("john"))
           {
               WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("john", "secret");
           }

           if (!Roles.GetRolesForUser("john").Contains("Administrator"))
           {
               Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "john" }, new[] { "Administrator" });
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Specify the memebership and role providers in your web.config:

   ```
   <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
     <providers>
       <clear/>
       <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
     </providers>
   </roleManager>
   <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
     <providers>
       <clear/>
       <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
     </providers>
   </membership>
   ```
5. Run the migration in your package manager console:

   ```
   update-database -verbose
   ```

Comment: Hi, I can make this solution half way. I have in fact to run update-database twice because the first time the database is created but not tables. I have the error "Cannot open database "WorkoutPlannerDb" requested by the login. The login failed." I guess it's because InitializeDatabaseConnection re-open a new connection instead of using the first one?

Comment: AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true; is very scary to use. It automatically migrates the database whenever you change your code-first DbContext and should never be used in production environment. It is extremely difficult to recover from breaking changes in DB, since you have no migration steps to trace back from. Instead use "add-migration" to explicitly add migration steps for each change to code-first DB model.

Comment: @Darin: Sorry to bring up an older question, but would this still apply if you separate out the EF context from your web project? I can't imagine you'd reference WebMatrix.* and System.Web.Security as that created dependencies that shouldn't exist at a data level... (Maybe I should make a question for this?)

Comment: @BradChristie - Did you ever find an answer to your last question?  I am trying to seed all of my database data in a 'Core' project and then just consume that data from the user interface projects (e.g. web, mobile, etc.).  What progress have you had?

Comment: This website comes close to what I'm looking for but I still think something is missing.  Does anyone else find it odd that we'd have references to the WebSecurity namespace in the data access layer?