# How to seed Register & Login data using Entity Framework & SimpleMembership

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

Using SimpleMembership provider in MVC-4, I am trying to seed Registration details for few users, as below

```
public class ContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AccountsContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(AccountsContext context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);
        context.UserProfiles.Add(new UserProfile { UserId = 1, UserName = "admin" });
        context.UserProfiles.Add(new UserProfile { UserId = 2, UserName = "user1" });            
    }
}
```

But I am unable to set `password` & `confirmPassword`, since they are not found in UserProfile class. They are located in RegisterModel class, which could not be accessed directly from AccountsContext.

Answer (score 1):

if You're using build-in MembershipProvider

use System.Web.Security.Membership to manage UserProfile

```
MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser("admin", "p@ssword");
UserProfile profile = (UserProfile)ProfileBase.Create(newUser.UserName);
//.. update profile then save in context
```

Comment: `ProfileBase.Create(newUser.UserName);` returns ProfileBase class, thus assignment to `UserProfile = profile` throws type mismatch error. Any suggestions ?

Comment: oops just cast it `(UserProfile)ProfileBase.Create(newUser.UserName);`

Comment: `Models.UserProfile` & `System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase` is not having any inheritence relationship among themselves. How can we typecast explicitly in this case. ??

Comment: if you want to use asp.net membership out of the box. Your model must inherit [System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilebase.aspx) the abstract ProfileBase class provides convenient interfaces for implementing membership.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do this?

```
SimpleMembershipProvider _membership = Membership.Provider;
_membership.CreateUserAndAccount("username", "password");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work: [More details here](http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/). [Also Possible duplication here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662587/how-to-initialize-database-with-entity-framework-and-membership-tables)

```
protected override void Seed(EfDb context)
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

        if (!Roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
        {
            Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");
        }

        if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("john"))
        {
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("john", "secret");
        }

        if (!Roles.GetRolesForUser("john").Contains("Administrator"))
        {
            Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "john" }, new[] { "Administrator" });
        }

    }
```